# Is Angularjs 1.6.+ is compatible with jQuery 3.5+?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, version-control, compatibility, migrate

I was using Angularjs 1.6.10 and JQuery 3.3.1, Can I use jQuery 3.5.1 with Angularjs 1.6?

Comment: Good question. All I know is that for AngularJS 1.8 they support jQuery 2.1+ but suggest jQuery 3.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Found this in the docs [FAQ](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq):

[image]. Unfortunately didn't find much from your specific versions, but as a general idea:

- jQuery is compatible with your DOM, whatever the version is
- Angular does not force you to use jQuery
- You can call jQuery functions from Angular in the same manner you call any functions

So, you should be able to use jQuery and Angular whatever the versions, are it should work, however, we do not know what jQuery-based work did the Angular team, if jQuery is present, so, the sure thing is to create a new branch of your project using your version control system, upgrade the versions to the ones you prefer, make sure that it is stable to the best of your knowledge and then perform massive tests. If everything works, then you should be okay for the time being. If, in the future you encounter some problems regarding the versions, then there will likely be new and better resources, which will allow you to have a superior solution to your problem at that point than the ones you would have now.