# Any alternative of using iframe ( jQuery 2.1.3 source code )?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Please see jQuery source code: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js
If we search for text "<iframe" then we can see below function:

```
function defaultDisplay( nodeName ) {
    var doc = document,
        display = elemdisplay[ nodeName ];

    if ( !display ) {
        display = actualDisplay( nodeName, doc );

        // If the simple way fails, read from inside an iframe
        if ( display === "none" || !display ) {

            // Use the already-created iframe if possible
            iframe = (iframe || jQuery( "<iframe frameborder='0' width='0' height='0'/>" )).appendTo( doc.documentElement );

            // Always write a new HTML skeleton so Webkit and Firefox don't choke on reuse
            doc = iframe[ 0 ].contentDocument;

            // Support: IE
            doc.write();
            doc.close();

            display = actualDisplay( nodeName, doc );
            iframe.detach();
        }

        // Store the correct default display
        elemdisplay[ nodeName ] = display;
    }

    return display;
}
```

This works fine, however, our Web firewall blocks this file because of suspecting possible iframe injection. It seems the function is creating iframe element and appends the element. Later, it uses the iframe to get the display value.

Any workaround/alternatives of using iframe so that we can replace the line which reads:

```
iframe = (iframe || jQuery( "<iframe frameborder='0' width='0' height='0'/>" )).appendTo( doc.documentElement );
```

Kindly note that I cannot change the firewall provider. Further, this is on AngularJS 1.4.5, does it have any dependencies on jQuery version? All I know is that AngularJS 1.4.5 requires jQuery, but not sure which version.

Has anybody used AngularJS 1.4.5 with latest jQuery version?

Comment: Fix your firewall, or don't rely on CDN-hosted code?

Comment: Get rid of the broken web firewall, or host your own version of jQuery without the offending line.

Comment: That code doesn't exist in jQuery 3.3.1, so you could try upgrading.

Comment: @user229044 Can't change firewall due to compliance.

Comment: @AKX are you suggesting that I remove the jQuery("<iframe .." line? any other valid alternative?

Comment: @Barmar just wondering if will upgrading break anything? this is because we are using Angulajs 1 (pretty old app) and it may have some dependency.

Comment: It's possible. Some deprecated features were removed in 3.x.

Comment: This is a question about how to circumvent a firewall rule for some specific snippet of text. That the text is code is irrelevant to the actual question, so this really has nothing to do with programming. It's really not clear what you want here. The options are to change the firewall or change the code, there are very clearly no other options. If you can't change the broken firewall, you are left with only one option, which you seem to be unwilling to pursue.

Comment: Where I mentioned that I am unwilling? It's just the question about compatibility. Further, this is not my home firewall as the app belongs to the US Government and as you might have guess, I have no power to ask them to change. I am ready to change, just in-case someone faced this situation and was able to fix by altering the logic.

Comment: Yep, thought so. Angular will use jQuery only if it's available but will default to it's minimal built-in version called jqLite. There is no direct dependency on jQuery itself. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/9bff2ce8fb170d7a33d3ad551922d7e23e9f82fc/src/jqLite.js. If you don't need jQuery for anything else, remove it.

Comment: @phuzi AngularJS uses jQuery, however they haven't provided exact version mapping between jQuery and AngularJS. I am just trying to see if anybody have tried and worked different versions. Unfortunately, some overly sensitive people have marked my question inappropriate, but this was helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65284866/is-angularjs-1-6-is-compatible-with-jquery-3-5

Comment: @TechTurtle The answer on the linked question includes a screenshot from the AngularJS FAQ (link: https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#does-angularjs-use-the-jquery-library-) that states "Yes, AngularJS ___can___ use jQuery if it's present in your app..." (emphasis mine). There is no requirement to have jQuery loaded in to your page to use AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the Angular JS FAQ, there's [a question about the use of jQuery in Angular JS 1.4.5](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/docs/misc/faq#does-angular-use-the-jquery-library-) (*emphasis is mine*)

> ##### Does AngularJS use the jQuery library?
>
> Yes, Angular ***can use jQuery if it's present in your app*** when the application is being bootstrapped. If jQuery is not present in your script path, Angular falls back to its own implementation of the subset of jQuery that we call jQLite.
>
> Angular 1.3 only supports jQuery 2.1 or above. jQuery 1.7 and newer might work correctly with Angular but we don't guarantee that.

As you can see from this, there is no hard dependency upon jQuery at all and Angular JS will use it's own version of jQuery, jQLite.

You should be okay to completely remove jQuery from your Angular JS page(s) assuming it's not being used anywhere else.

Unfortunately it's not clear whether the "supports jQuery 2.1 or above" includes major versions.

Comment: true, but we have other libraries the depends on jquery like bootstrap etc. so we have to include it in out source code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with:

```
//iframe = (iframe || jQuery( "<iframe frameborder='0' width='0' height='0'/>" )).appendTo( doc.documentElement );

if (!iframe){
 iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
 iframe.frameBorder = iframe.width = iframe.height = 0;
}
doc.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
doc = iframe[0].contentDocument;

//rest of the code
```

This way, now the proxy server isn't showing any error message as text "<iframe" is not found and we are creating by other means of JS.